# Change the Mandatory field based on selection in webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I have Webform with a radio button type field named as "preferred contact method", for selecting email or phone.

When user select the email I want to set the email field as mandatory or if user select the phone I want to set phone field as mandatory.

How to handle this in Webform Drupal 7.

Comment: You just take a try for webform_conditional module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting thing to have, but i don't think Webform support such a functionality. However they are some other way to achieve the same result.

Using [Webform Conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional). you can have two sets of  hidden questions, and only one set of question could be visible base on user selected choice.

If user click on phone the first set of question will be display to user where the phone is a mandatory and email optional.

If user click on email the second set of question will be display to user where you can have email as mandatory and phone as optional.

You can ready more about alternative ways [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/972184) .

Answer (score 0):

You can add '#states' for the field in hook_form_alter() . Check this question [How to make a form required with states?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14173/how-to-make-a-form-required-with-states)