# Show a required textfield when user select only ups shipping service on checkout form

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce for my client ecommerce site. For shipping methods I am using [commerce_shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping), [commerce_ups](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ups), [commerce_usps](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_usps).

Everything is working but my client wants when a user select any *ups shipping service* a textbox should be shown and should be required.

What I have done till now :

I have created a pane which contains a textbox using order setting. And that taexbox is showing on checkout form . But when I make this textbox as a required field than it is not possible to submit the form when user select usps or flat rate shipping services.

So how I can show a textfield on checkout form which should be required only when user select any ups shippping service.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the conditional fields module? https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: Shipping services is not available in manage dependencies with textfield which i have created using order setting . Field is created by following this tutorial.https://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-fieldgroup-panes-screencast

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this via #states property in form API.

More information about that can be found here:
[How to make a form required with states?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14173/how-to-make-a-form-required-with-states)

Personally i only used it to hide/display form elements, but required/non-required should be possible as well.