# How to make an entity reference field required using states

Tags: 8

I need to make an entity reference field in my form be required based on the state, the code below is working with other fields, but not my entity reference field.

```
$form['schedule_publish_date'] ['#states'] =  array(
 'required' => array(
  ':input[name="moderation_state[0]"]' => array('value' =>"published"),
 ),
);
```

this is the source code of the entity reference field. Am I putting in the wrong name for the form item?

```
<fieldset data-drupal-selector="edit-schedule-publish-date" id="edit-schedule-publish-date" class="js-form-item form-item js-form-wrapper form-wrapper">
  <legend>
<span class="fieldset-legend">Schedule Publish Date</span>
```

```
      </div>
```

the moderation state is not what I am having trouble reaching. It's the schedule publish date, which is an entity reference and doesnt become "required" when it should.

Comment: Could you please mention what modules you are using ? For example, where comes from the "moderation_state" input ? Are you sure with the value you are setting ?
Have a look to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14173/how-to-make-a-form-required-with-states) would be interesting for you I think.

Comment: Be aware that using states to make a value required is not a guarantee. It uses client side JavaScript that could be disabled or altered. You should always include a form validation callback to make sure the value is really there after submission.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific form element with the moderation state, since they are added as action submit buttons, but you could add one like this:

```
  if (!empty($form['moderation_state']['widget'])) {
    $form['moderation_state_hidden'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#title' => 'moderation_state_hidden',
      '#value' => $form['moderation']['widget'][0]['#default_value'],
    ];
  }
```

Then you could refer to it in your states array like this:

```
$form['schedule_publish_date'] ['#states'] =  array(
 'required' => array(
  ':input[name="moderation_state_hidden"]' => array('value' =>"published"),
 ),
);
```

But using states doesn't really make sense because you can't change the moderation status of a hidden field or a non-ajax submit button.

So in that case, you could just update the form element to be required

```
  if (!empty($form['moderation_state']['widget']) && $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] == 'published') {
    $form['schedule_publish_date']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: _But using states doesn't really make sense because you can't change the moderation status of a hidden field or a non-ajax submit button._ Very good point. just wrap the whole `$form['schedule_publish_date']` in an if-statement depending on the published state instead.

Comment: no the moderation state is not what i am having trouble reaching. its the schedule publish date, which is an entity reference and doesnt become "required" when it should

Comment: I have updated code for how to access target_id of a entity reference field, see the part like this: ['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;